# Adding a new life once a score has been reached in a Java game

Tags: java

Im developing a java game where you kill enemies and earn points. Every 3000 points you obtain id like to add 1 more life point to the players ship. My current implementation means that once you've reached 3000 points, you get 1 life for every kill (which is not what i want). What i would like is 1 life for every 3000 point (1 life at 3000, 1 more life at 6000). How would i go about doing this ?
My score method:

```
public void incScore(int inc){
    //hit asteroid 100
    //hit spaceship 250
    //mothership = 500
    score = score + inc;
    if (score >= 3000){
        playerShip.life = playerShip.life +1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (before increasing the score):

```
  if (score /3000 < (score + inc) / 3000)
        playerShip.life++;
```

Comment: I can't see a real difference with OP's post

Answer (score 1):

Use an extra variable like lifecount.

```
int lifecount = 1;

public void incScore(int inc){
//hit asteroid 100
//hit spaceship 250
//mothership = 500 
score = score + inc;
if (score >= 3000*lifecount){
    playerShip.life = playerShip.life +1;
    lifecount++;
}
}
```